# Auto login vBulletin Forum from Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, vbulletin

Actually I want to integrate vBulletin forum and Wordpress site. when i click on lo-gin /sign-up menu then vBulletin redirect to Wordpress site.

When I logged from Wordpress site then automatically logged in vBulletin forum.I wondered many places but not getting any proper result.so please let me know this feature is possible and how i integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [vBSSO](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=270517) (or [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/vbsso/))

Comment: Thank you but did you getting my question. I want to logging Wordpress site as well as forum site at same time.

Comment: 1 time login (on WP or vB) then you will be automatically loged into both CMS (no need to login again). Single Sign On, isn't ?

Comment: My v Bulletin Version is 5.0.2 and this plug-in support less then 3.0.xx Version. So please let me know how i do this i want to log-in on both sites at the same time.

Comment: Yep, vBSSO only supports vB4 and vB3. Afak there is not yet a SSO solution for vB5. Also vB5 is new for me so I would not be able to help.